# Multi-threading in Windows PHP 7.4

Tags: php, php-extension, pecl

I'm looking for a way to do multi-threading in PHP 7.4 on Windows. My current build is TS, x64, VC16.

I looked into the [`parallel`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.parallel.php) ([on github](https://github.com/krakjoe/parallel)) extension, but on [PECL](https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/parallel/1.1.3/), there is only support for PHP 7.3, and with VC15.

Is there an alternative library with windows support, or is there a way to build `parallel` myself?

Comment: Why do you say 7.3 and VC15 specifically? I think it requires PHP 7.2+, ZTS, and pthreads. Windows may already have built extension at https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/parallel/

Comment: @bishop I'm pretty sure on windows the compiler and php version of the extension's build must match that of your PHP build. PECL has php 7.3 and VC15.  My PHP is 7.4 and VC16. Regardless, I tried the PECL extension and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I've been fighting with this on and off for a few months.

The only successful setup of just pthreads was on php 7.2

I got parallels working on php 7.3 but this did not expose the pthreads classes that my project was using.

I have a feeling you may need to compile your own